# Centralized way to manage authentication

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm implementing authorization in my app in which I use Alamofire. I have an authorization-token to add to the header of each `HTTP` request I make, then check their responses to see if server returned `401` status code or not? and if it did, log-out the user.

What is the best practice? Is there an easy way to add this behaviour to each request?

My desired goal is to have single source of truth in my code where I check for `401 error code`.

I didn't find a satisfing answer looking around Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: You can always write a wrapper for the alamofire code and make all your other code call that.

Comment: My first question would be why you bother to use Alamofire nowadays. What benefit do you get from it?

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik if I use response request and check I need to check it with my all every single request. I needed it should be any global way to do that or any alamofire method of class for that?? so I can use it in one place. thank you

Comment: create one global communicator for all your requests, from it all requests will send all responses will received in one place, use blocks to obtain response

Answer (score 2):

`Alamofire` provides two `protocol`s named `RequestAdapter` and `RequestRetrier`.

`RequestAdapter` gets informed every-time a request is **about** to be made. This is the perfect place to inject your token.

`RequestRetrier` gets informed every-time a requests fails due to **any** reasons. You can check for failure reasons and detect the 401-unauthorized case, and send a global notification to the system (and probably manage it in `AppDelegate`)

You have to assign them to the current `Session` managing requests.

You can also read Alamofire docuemnts for [how to implement simple OAuth](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#adapting-and-retrying-requests).

Answer (score 0):

Your main method to send request can look like this

```
func sendJsonRequest(
    accessPoint: String,
    method: HTTPMethod,
    parameters: Parameters,
    headers: HTTPHeaders,
    encoding: ParameterEncoding = JSONEncoding.default,
    success: @escaping (_ response: DataResponse<Any>, _ json: NSDictionary) -> Void,
    failure: @escaping (_ response: DataResponse<Any>, _ error: Error) -> Void
) -> DataRequest {
    return Alamofire.request(
            accessPoint,
            method: method,
            parameters: parameters,
            encoding: encoding,
            headers: headers
    ).validate().responseJSON(queue: getQueue()) { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success (let data):
            success(response, data)
        case .failure(let error):

            if response.response?.statusCode == 401 {
                // Do what you want to do here
            } else {
                failure(response, error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and other methods like get, post and all can call it internally like

```
func post(
    accessPoint: String,
    parameters: Parameters,
    headers: HTTPHeaders,
    success: @escaping (_ response: DataResponse<Any>, _ json: NSDictionary) -> Void,
    failure: @escaping (_ response: DataResponse<Any>, _ error: Error) -> Void
) -> DataRequest {
    return sendJsonRequest(
            accessPoint: accessPoint,
            method: .post,
            parameters: parameters,
            headers: headers,
            success: success,
            failure: failure
    )
}


func get(
    accessPoint: String,
    headers: HTTPHeaders,
    success: @escaping (_ response: DataResponse<Any>, _ json: NSDictionary) -> Void,
    failure: @escaping (_ response: DataResponse<Any>, _ error: Error) -> Void
) -> DataRequest {
    return jsonRequest(
            accessPoint: accessPoint,
            method: .get,
            parameters: [:],
            headers: headers,
            encoding: URLEncoding.default,
            success: success,
            failure: failure
    )
}
```

This can be in your `BaseService` and other services can extend this.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanna ask about is how to validate user's cookies is available.
I handle it like that:

1. Using  **HTTPCookieStorage** to store user's cookies(contain token、expired time、value and others)
   IN Login in

   ```
       Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: para, encoding: URLEncoding.default,headers: headers).response { (response) in
       guard response.response?.statusCode == 200 else{
           // error handling
           return
       }
       let headerFields = response.response?.allHeaderFields as? [String: String]
       let Url = response.request?.url
       let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: headerFields!, for: Url!)
       HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookies(cookies, for: Url!, mainDocumentURL:nil)
   }
   ```
2. HTTPCookieStorage will **automatically delete** expired cookies,In
   my app,max to only one Cookies,so I use

   ```
       if HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies == [] {
       //error
       }
   ```

to check out whether the token is invalid or you can using **NSHTTPCookieManagerCookiesChanged** Notification to observe cookies changed.

3. when you using alamofire after that,alamofire will set this token to HTTP request headers.